# SVG not rendering properly in Chrome until vising the full PATH of image

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, google-maps-markers

This is for a Google Maps API marker, I have an SVG file my web Server and for whatever reason it doesn't render properly until I visit the actual full path of the image in Chrome browser.

for example (after clearing cache) visit site: SVG doesn't render properly.

Then I visit **http://localhost/static/rdot.svg** then go back to localhost:80 and it renders properly? What is the reason for this? Works perfectly fine on Firefox 57.0

My icon looks being imported like this in JavaScript:

```
    var rushingIcon = {
    url: 'static/rdot.svg',
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), // scaled size 16 px
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
  };
```

Comment: any messages in Chrome's Javascript console?

Comment: Just an error about favicon and [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
send @ jquery.min.js:5
ajax @ jquery.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ map.js:2